# Insert and retrieve files to and from Mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

How can we insert **word/image or any kind of files** in MySQL database and how can we retrieve those files from the MySQL database and use in php programming?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application flow and solution. You can store the files physically and store the file path in DB. Or you can use BLOB. Please refer the link for mySQL BLOB,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

Thanks.